# How to create draggable textfield over image. Like Instagram tag

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am creating an image over textfield but it's not dragging. And how to add more textfield dynamically. Tag people one or more tag text field on image. How to get this. And remove text field also. After adding text in textfield only label text display over image.

Comment: It is not really a text field it is called popup menu and you can check https://pub.dev/packages/popover package out to achieve something like that

Comment: It's a **field** - not a "feild" ...